# Permission denied on mkdir()

Tags: php, error-handling, mkdir

I'm getting the following error when trying to call mkdir() on a server...

> Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]:
>   Permission denied in
>   /home/server/public_html/wp-content/themes/mytheme/catimages/cat-images.php
>   on line 373

The function is below. Its attempting to create a folder under the site's "wp-content/uploads folder". I've verified that the PHP Version is 5.2.15 and that the files inside the theme folder are writable, but that does not necessarily means the uploads folder is writable I suppose.

How can I find out if the uploads folder is writable?

```
protected function category_images_base_dir()
{
    // Where should the dir be? Get the base WP uploads dir
    $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $base_dir = $wp_upload_dir[ 'basedir' ];
    // Append our subdir
    $dir = $base_dir . '/cat-images';
    // Does the dir exist? (If not, then make it)
    if ( ! file_exists( $dir ) ) {
        mkdir( $dir ); //THIS IS LINE 373
    }
    // Now return it
    return $dir;
}
```

Comment: You may need to set the resurice flag of mkdir ;)

Comment: :) this is actualy funny: how can you find out ? -> you get the Warning: ... Permision denied ... , so you know for shure the folder is not writable by the webserver user . if you have ssh access do a chmod -R 777 /home/server/public_html/wp-content, if you don't have ssh access you can open you're favorite ftp client , browse to the wp-content folder then right click on wp-content and most ftp clients will have a permissions tab or box somewhere around there witch you will use to change permissions .

Comment: @poelinca If I could, I'd downvote that. Are you seriously suggesting his directories to be world readable, so the "problem goes away"?!

Comment: @Linus Kleen: his wp-content files are allready world readable no question about that . They are not wirtable yes and by the looks he needs access to write some files how would you go about and do that ? you test if the folder is writable and if not you don't write the file anymore ? is that a solution ? You are right tough it sould have been `chmod -R 777 /home/server/public_html/wp-content/uploads` , or eaven a better one `chown -R "webserveruser" /home/server/public_html/wp-content/uploads`

Comment: @poelinca: that's exactly a right use case for the "group" privileges - you still own the dir (and the files), but you are allowing access to users from another group. 777 is probably excessive; Giving ownership to the server user may give you trouble when you need to manage the files (delete old ones etc).

Comment: @Piskvor: you're absolutley right , however most shared hosting companyes whont allow ssh access , they whont tell you anything about groups not eaven the webserver user , you probably need to call them or submit tikets then wait for them to do this hence i recomended 777 in the first place .

Comment: @poelinca: Indeed, that's the approach "a few hours spent coding around it will spare you ten minutes on the phone."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`is_writable()` is probably the function you're looking for.

http://cz.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php says:

> Returns TRUE if the filename exists and is writable. The filename argument may be a directory name allowing you to check if a directory is writable.

Also, the directly next line is relevant here:

> Keep in mind that PHP may be accessing the file as the user id that the web server runs as (often 'nobody').

In other words, check if your directory is writable by the user id of the web server - this may be a different user id than yours! Set the appropriate permissions - e.g. set the usergroup of the folder to that of the server's user, and grant read, write, and execute to group. (`chgrp somegroup uploads; chmod g+r uploads; chmod g+w uploads; chmod g+x uploads`)

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer. I'm going to insert some additional code checks to verify is_writable() state of the parent folder and add exception handling in that event.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the parent folder is writable to the process that the web server runs as.

Edit: Oops, premature reply. Does your host give you a GUI file browser thingy?